# How are we supposed to set up the @SQSListener deletion policy with Spring Cloud AWS 3.0.2?

Tags: spring-cloud-aws

The only way I've been able to figure out how to set this up is with the following override in my configuration:

```
@Bean("myFactory")
@ConditionalOnClass(SqsAsyncClient.class)
SqsMessageListenerContainerFactory<Object> mySqsListenerContainerFactory(
    SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient) {
  return SqsMessageListenerContainerFactory.builder()
      .configure(
          options ->
              options.acknowledgementMode(
                  AcknowledgementMode.valueOf("ON_SUCCESS")))
      .sqsAsyncClient(sqsAsyncClient)
      .build();
}
```

And this in my `@SQSListener`:

```
@SqsListener(
      value = "myQueue",
      factory = "myFactory")
```

I haven't figured out how to configure this so that the `io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.sqs.SqsAutoConfiguration` class can set the acknowledgement mode and I can get the benefit of letting Spring autoconfigure everything for me that I need. Can anyone advise me on how this should be set up moving forward?

Prior to Spring Cloud AWS 3.x, we set up the `@SQSListener` as follows, which is no longer supported it seems:

```
@SqsListener(
      value = "myQueue",
      deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spring Cloud AWS 3.0, the default acknowledgement mode is `ON_SUCCESS` [0].

Using another acknowledgement mode can currently only be done via the factory, but with the next version (3.1), it will be possible again to set it directly in the `@SqsListener` annotation [1].

[0] https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.2/reference/html/index.html#sqscontaineroptions-descriptions

[1] https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/pull/870